# How to set the display picture of a phone contact programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, contacts

I need to change the display picture of phone's store contacts in code.

I have search around, and found out how to get the contacts but no information on how to change properties. Seems to be read only.

Is there any way to do this? i only care for the picture not any other properties basically.

Any workaround how to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your able to edit the People applications data/contacts; as that probably result in security issues, if that's what you mean?

Alternatively you could grab all the contacts like you've said you can do and change the persons icon from within your app using a small piece of code such as: `Image.Source = "/AppName;component/Images/ImageName"`?

Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you but my goal is to change the picture of the actual contact in the public hub, so when you get a call for example you'll have that picture showing.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, but as I said before I pretty sure It's impossible to change any data in the public hub as it would mean that you would be able to delete contacts aswell, which could also include other security implications? Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Thanks for your time anyway, this is just frustrating! They could just prompt the user that the application wants to change data in the public hub...pfff

Answer (score 0):

I think it can not be overload people contact in windows phone because they gave read only access but we can add a contact r view the contact detail http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Contacts-and-Calendar-9fce5e26 this link helps u a little